# jsf components rendering very slowly in IE ,but render faster in FF and chrome

Tags: performance, jsf, browser

I have a JSF application where the UI components render very slowly in IE7 but give a much better performance.Dont know what can be done ,but just throwing this question out for suggestion if any setting/configuration makes it perform better

Comment: Can you give more information? Which version of JSF, which libraries (`Facelets`, `Richfaces`, `Tomahawk`, `Icefaces`, etc.) ? What are the components you are defining in your pages? Do you have a lot of Javascript? ...

Answer (score 1):

IE6 and IE7 have a poor JS engine and a buggy slow HTML table renderer. Thus, there's either extremely a lot of JS code, or an extremely large HTML table in your JSF page. Solutions to both are obvious enough, but I can't give them in detail as long as you tell nothing about the JSF implementation and component libraries used.

I can at least tell that Woodstock (the "Visual JSF" thing in Netbeans) is known to be hogging slow like that. It comes along with a lot of JS code (components are practically rendered/built in JS). It is fortunately abandoned since 2 years.